# how i can solve this in recursion method

Tags: java, recursion

actually I worked with diamond shape recursively but showing me problem and i don't know how i solve it here the shape :

```
                                * 
                              * * * 
                            * * * * * 
                          * * * * * * * 
                        * * * * * * * * * 
                      * * * * * * * * * * * 
                    * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
                  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
                * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
              * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
            * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
          * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
        * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
      * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
                                * 
                              * * * 
                            * * * * * 
                          * * * * * * * 
                        * * * * * * * * * 
                      * * * * * * * * * * * 
                    * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
                  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
                * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
              * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
            * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
          * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
        * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
      * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

just up ..

this is my code :

```
public static void draw(int shape, int space, PrintWriter output) {

    boolean x = true;

    if (shape < 1) {
        System.out.print("");
    } else if (x) {
        draw(shape - 2, space - 1,  output);
        row(shape, space, output);
    } else {
        row(shape, space, output);
        draw(shape - 2, space - 1,  output);
    }

    if (space == shape) {
        draw(shape - 2, space - 1,  output);
    }
}

public static void row(int shape, int space, PrintWriter output) {

    for (int i = 0; i < space; i++) {
        if (i < space - shape) {
            System.out.print("  ");// print space
        } else {
            System.out.print("* ");//print a star
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

the program java i/o and size diamond : 3 ,5 ,7 and 33

Comment: What happens when you run your program? How does the output differ from what you want? I suggest you learn how to debug your own code. You can either add `System.out.println()` calls to view execution order and value of variables or use a debugger from your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

There are several types of recursion: 1) preorder, 2) inorder, and 3) postorder. Here you actually need to do a combination of preorder and postorder recursion. In words:

1. Draw a line of stars
2. Draw the rest of the diamond (this is the recursive part)
3. Draw another line of stars the same length as the one in step 1

Hopefully this will help you see how you can fix your code to get the diamond shape you want. Notice how I am thinking about the solution to the problem in English without worrying about any Java syntax. The only technical detail that I use is the idea of recursion, but I still describe it **in words**.